# FiPy convection with a given velocity field

Tags: python, pde, fipy

I'm using FiPy to model convection/diffusion of a chemical in a given velocity field, and I'm having problems setting this field as ConvectionTerm coefficient.

My velocity field is expressed by two bidimensional arrays, let's say `Ugrid` for horizontal velocities and `Vgrid` for vertical ones, representing the values at the faces of each cell. For this reason, I'd say that the proper way to set this field as `coeff` parameter for the ConvectionTerm would be assigning it to a FaceVariable.

However, I don't get how to pass these two arrays as `value` for the FaceVariable. Apparently, I have no problems in setting the field as CellVariable by using `value = [np.ravel(Ugrid),np.ravel(Vgrid)]` and the convection simulation appears to make sense as well, but I don't think this is correct, as I briefly mentioned above.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An important consideration with FiPy is that the mesh indexing is not based on grid indexing so mapping from a grid array to cell values should not assume that the mesh is ordered in any particular way. This makes it necessary to use some form of interpolation. Let's first construct a velocity field with grid indexing where the points lie on the grid points (not cell centers).

```
from fipy import Grid2D, CellVariable, FaceVariable
from fipy import ConvectionTerm, DiffusionTerm, TransientTerm
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

dx = 0.5
nx = 7
dy = 0.5
ny = 7

xy = np.zeros((nx, ny, 2))
xy[:, :,  0] = np.mgrid[0:nx, 0:ny][0] * dx
xy[:, :, 1] = np.mgrid[0:nx, 0:ny][1] * dy

u = xy[..., 0] + xy[..., 1]
v = xy[..., 0] * xy[..., 1]
```

We now have a `(u, v)` velocity field each of shape `nx, ny` and the corresponding coordinates, `xy`, of shape `(nx, ny, 2)`. Let's say we want to interpolate that to a FiPy mesh with the same domain, but a different grid.

```
m = Grid2D(nx=3, ny=3, dx=1.0, dy=1.0)
```

The mesh doesn't necessarily need to align with the grid points for the velocity field. We can then interpolate to that mesh with

```
xy_interp = np.array(m.faceCenters).swapaxes(0, 1)
u_interp = interpolate.griddata(xy.reshape(-1, 2), u.flatten(), xy_interp, method='cubic')
v_interp = interpolate.griddata(xy.reshape(-1, 2), v.flatten(), xy_interp, method='cubic')
```

where `xy_interp` are the mesh's face centers. Note that using `griddata` requires that the `xy_interp` are inside the `xy` otherwise it gives nan values. Once we have the interpolated values, we can set up the FiPy velocity field.

```
velocity = FaceVariable(mesh=m, rank=1)
velocity[0, :] = u_interp
velocity[1, :] = v_interp
```

Note that the coefficient for the `ConvectionTerm` can be a `FaceVariable` or a `CellVariable`. Once we have the velocity, we're ready to set up and solve the equation.

```
var = CellVariable(mesh=m)
eqn = (TransientTerm() + ConvectionTerm(velocity) == DiffusionTerm(1.0))
eqn.solve(var, dt=1.0)
```

This runs without error for me.

[Link to complete script for this problem](https://gist.github.com/wd15/28f1b13f9f570fdcc21b9cb22c48bf12)